# Match all after hostname

Tags: regex

How can I match all that comes after a hostname. If I have:

```
    http://test.someweb.net/category/subcategory/?some=value
```

I want to match:

```
    /category/subcategory/?some=value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/http:\/\/[^/]+(.*)/
```

The first matched group (`(.*)`) is the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "http://asjahsjahsjahs.ashags.asjahs/andbcb/c/d"

m = url.match(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*(\/.*)/);

m[1] ; //# =>  /andbcb/c/d
```